# Angular universal starter: Wha't the purpose of the service TransferState?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have to admit, I don't understand the purpose and goal of the service `TransferState` in the `Angular universal starter` app  (https://github.com/angular/universal-starter).

I'm guessing it's to share data between the client and the server, but I'm not sure in which case that would apply or that should be applied.

Does someone do understand and would be able to explain me the purpose with a simple example?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GitHub Issue answering your question.](https://github.com/FrozenPandaz/ng-universal-demo/issues/20)

I have two guesses.

1. Third bullet point from the [Universal Gotchas](https://github.com/angular/universal#universal-gotchas) - the mentioned example could be TransferModule
2. Preboot.js Enhancement, because it doesn't support API calls right now

Comment: cool thx for pointing that out, also heard that on the gutter channel respectively it's use to only perform http requests on the server side. I'm not yet there with my project to perform my http requests. I soon as I'll do, I'll confirm this and close this question

Comment: can now confirm that without the use of TransferState or any other solution, http queries are run in the server and on the client side. Now I should try to figure out if TransferState is still the actually workaround to solve this or if there is an official way

Answer (score -1):

TransferState is not currently listed in https://universal.angular.io/api/universal/index.html#typedoc-main-index which may indicate that the feature is a work in progress and not intended to be used, that it is not intended to be used directly (e.g. is called from within the library itself), or it may be a simple omission, or may be excluded for some other reason...

However, upon looking through the code for `TransferState` it appears to be very sparse with the exception of:

https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/src/modules/transfer-state/server-transfer-state.ts

and

https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/src/modules/transfer-state/transfer-state.ts

The major clue here appears to be in the inclusion of `import * as serialize from 'serialize-javascript';` in the server file, and a number of different `.map` statements, among other hints as to the purpose of the file.

From a cursory inspection, it appears that it is simply a small section of code for converting the state of one file or io type to another. And example would be the code:

```
toJson(): any {
    const obj = {};
    Array.from(this.keys())
      .forEach(key => {
        obj[key] = this.get(key);
      });
    return obj;
  }
```

in the `transfer-state.ts` file. It should be possible to call this function like so:

```
myFile.transferState.toJson();
```

In order to transfer the state of a given input into JSON data. This appears to be a duplicate of much pre-existing functionality, and this also may be a reason why it is not listed in the documentation.

Comment: Thx for digging into it and explanation. When I run this `universal starter app` the page is rendered with the following code in the `head` `<script>window['TRANSFER_STATE'] = {"message":"Hello World"}</script>` ... I was just asking myself then, maybe the goal here is to share data between client and server side, like for example the browser language for internationalization?

Comment: That is interesting. Tell you what, I'll install Angular Universal on my own site, then have a little dig around, see if I can find anymore info for you.

Comment: That would be cool ;) On my side I'm also trying universal with the goal to pack my static website and my dynamic app in a single app, if doing so I understand something, will post too

Comment: Actually passing the navigator language for internationalization wasn't an option for me respectively isn't the purpose of passing a state between client and server (I solve the language discovery with the request headers)...so yep still don't know a use case for this provider